# XBee Not Resetting on XCTU

Tags: configuration, reset, xbee

I'm connecting a XBee Series 2 on a breakout board to an Arduino to configure it. I soldered some header pins on to the breakout board to make the connections. Ultimately, I'm going to connect the Arduino with a Raspberry Pi over ZigBee.

I run XCTU on my Mac and the software recognizes the XBee device. I can write the PAN ID to it, though it won't let me update it to be in Coordinator API mode. It says to reset it, which I attempt to do by connecting the RST pin to ground. That doesn't work though.

How else can I attempt to manually reset the XBee? Or am I even going about coordinating the XBee in the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure RTS is connected as well -- that control signal is required to get into the bootloader when installing new firmware.

Comment: What pin does RST connect to and what pin does RTS connect to? I connected both RST and RTS to ground and that didn't work. I also connected RTS to 3.3V and RST to ground and that also didn't work.

Comment: Connect RTS to the RTS pin of the USB adapter connected to your Mac. If it's not too difficult, you might as well connect CTS for full hardware flow control (but CTS isn't necessary for the firmware update process).

Comment: Thank you for the help. That also didn't work, so I ended up purchasing a Explorer USB which did the trick.